# QT Executable under windows

Tags: qt, dll, linker

I am statically linking an QT application, but for some reason when i open the executable i am getting errors for missing dlls.

Basically i am linking the following libs:

```
### LINKER FLAGS ###
LDFLAGS = -LC:/Qt/5.15.0/mingw81_32/lib

LDLIBS = -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core
```

Why am i getting errors for missing dlls when i am statically linking everything?

The compilation and linking passes correctly, the executable is generated also..i have no idea why it needs dlls.

EDIT:

Missing dlls:

```
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll,

libstdc++-6.dll,

Qt5Code.dll,

Qt5Widgets.dll
```

Comment: I just realized something really strange.The size of the actual executable is surprisingly small - 333kb.How is this possible?I expect to be atleast a few MBs with all those static libraries.

Comment: Apparently, for *Qt5Core* and *Qt5Widgets* you are linking the dynamic versions. If you have both static and dynamic versions in a *dir*, when encountering `-l${LIB}`, the linker will pick the dynamic one by default. To override that, specify the lib name - e.g.: *libQt5Core.a*.  For the others, pass the `-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc` flags to the linker.

Comment: I changed it to: LDLIBS = libQt5Widgets.a libQt5Gui.a libQt5Core.a -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++.But now it can't find libQt5Widgets.a,libQt5Gui.a, libQt5Core.a even tho they are in LDFLAGS = -LC:/Qt/5.15.0/mingw81_32/lib.

Comment: What happens if specifying them by full path? Also I'm not  sure thether *-LC:/Qt/5.15.0/mingw81_32/lib* is valid (because of the colon).

Comment: With the full path it finds and links them.But the executable is still too small and opening it again complains for Qt5Code.dll and Qt5Widgets.dll....

Comment: Then you only have the dynamically built Qt libs.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on CristiFati's reply, you need a line like this in your project file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

though I'd prefer:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

Note that if you want a *truly* standalone, self-contained binary, you'll need to build yourself a static Qt library. That's kind of a big deal, and unfortunately not as well documented as most of Qt-land is.

Comment: I am using an makefile.I added those and it dones't complain about them anymore.But i still can't fix Qt5Code.dll and Qt5Widgets.dll.I have them as libxxx.a, but somehow it doesn't link them statically.

Comment: Of course things don't work. If they did, I would have posted an answer myself. This doesn't qualify as an answer, as it doesn't solve the problem, it should have been a comment instead. Possibly, flag attracting  "-".